# How to apply a style border to a specific image

Tags: css, sass

I'm looking for a way to style CSS code for the border around a photo so that the left and bottom borders are angled and not vertical and Horizontal. Like on this picture:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear, please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... You want to transform the shape or only the border ? What's the final goal ? What do you already try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div.square {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.square:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50px;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 200px solid gray;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="placeholder">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear, but after looking your image linked below,
Use **[svg](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp)**

SVG has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and graphic images.

**[Example1:](https://codepen.io/rudesoul/pen/yLeEjRv)**

```
<svg width="100" height="100">

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"
  stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />

Circle from w3school

</svg>
```

**[EXAMPLE2:](https://codepen.io/rudesoul/pen/gOPKzBr)**

```
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />

Star from w3school

</svg>
```